# Automatic Maximize a window if user minimizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have a popup that can't be minimized before completing the operation. if a user minimize it, it should automatically gain focus and stay maximized.

I was able to achive the same in IE but not in chorme.
Following code works in IE:

```
var popup = window.open("https://www.google.com", "popup_window", "fullscreen");
  if (popup.outerWidth < screen.availWidth || popup.outerHeight < screen.availHeight)
  {
    popup.moveTo(0,0);
    popup.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
  }
```

This opened the screen without minimize button which solved the problem. 
Suggest an alternative for chrome

Answer (score 1):

Focusing the window this way isn't cross browser compatible. I guess Firefox, Chrome and Safari won't obey. I mean imagine if ads over the internet could oblige the user to keep the focus on their page... I would be a complete mess. So i think it's a security.

Comment: I completely understand your point, but I urgently need a wayout. I want to freeze the screen so that user will have to complete the task before leaving.

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain the need for the window to stay maximised? Focusing windows this way can be difficult, so perhaps the problem may best be solved by not requiring the window to stay maximised.